# Group theory vs Type theory

Tags: group-theory, type-theory

I have to state that I am not very proficient in either one or the other, but at first glance they both seem to tackle similar concepts.

[Wikipedia's definition of type theory:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory)

> In mathematics, logic, and computer science, a type theory is any of a
>   class of formal systems, some of which can serve as alternatives to
>   set theory as a foundation for all mathematics. In type theory, every
>   "term" has a "type" and operations are restricted to terms of a
>   certain type.

[Wikipedia's definition of group theory:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory)

> In mathematics and abstract algebra, group theory studies the
>   algebraic structures known as groups. The concept of a group is
>   central to abstract algebra: other well-known algebraic structures,
>   such as rings, fields, and vector spaces, can all be seen as groups
>   endowed with additional operations and axioms.

These definitions strike me as very similar, as from my limited understanding:

- Type theory seems to be about how sets have types and how types relate to each other using relational axioms and operations that allow type inference and relational deduction using maps and functors,
- And group theory seems to be about studying axioms and operations that are defined to be applied to certain elements of a type, such as vectors, matrices...etc and using deduction to determine the "set" (as I interpret it) in which the desired result lies.

Am I right to perceive them as similar in nature, or am I misunderstanding the premises of both?

Comment: That is not a "definition" of group theory, it is instead a vague introductory statement about how people think about and use group theory. Here is a definition of group theory:$$\text{group theory is the mathematical study of groups}$$Even that is not sufficient, though, not unless you also write down the definition of group:$$\text{a group is a set with a binary operation that satisfies}$$ $$\text{the associative law, the identity law, and the inverse law}$$

Comment: I see, so it's more specific than the definition I gave above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also think they are used very differently by mathematicians.

First note that while there is "group theory", the theory of groups, we should speak of *a* type theory. There is no "type theory" which would be "the theory of types". There are lots of type theories, depending on what kind of constructions you allow within your theory.

Also, a type theory is a purely formal system : just like set theory doesn't bother defining what a set is, there is no definition of what a type is in type theory (this being said, there are of course interpretations of type theory in other more "conventional" theories, like homotopy type theories, which in a sense aim to give a construction of what a type is).

On the other hand, a group, is a "concrete" object : we know what a group is, it's not purely formal. This being said, I guess you *could* see a group as a formal system with rewriting rules (I don't really know what that would look like or what use it would have, but I don't think it's an absurd notion) ; this is just not the point of view of mathematicians.

Comment: Could group theory be considered as a specialised agreed-upon subset of type theory?

Comment: I don't think it would make sense. Even if group theory could be really seen as a formal rewriting system, it would not most likely not be what we would call a type theory. To deserve that name, a formal system should satisfy a certain number of properties that group theories has absolutely no reason to satisfy (but I'm not a specialist in type theory, I couldn't go in much details).

Comment: Food for thought, thanks

Answer (score 5):

One way to see that group theory and type theory are orthogonal, is the fact that you can define a group in a type theory. Using a standard type theory with $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$ types, we can define a group as anything with the following type:
\begin{align}
  \newcommand\op{\!\cdot\!}
  \sum_{G : \mathfrak{U}}
  \sum_{{}\cdot{}: G \to G \to G}
  \sum_{e:G}
  \left(
    \prod_{a,b,c:G}\! (a \op b) \op c = a \op (b \op c)
    \lower{0.5em},
    \prod_{a:G} (a \op e = a,\, e \op a = a)
    \lower{0.5em},
    \prod_{a:G} \sum_{b:G} (a \op b = e,\, b \op a = e)
  \right)
\end{align}
Here $G$ is the set, $\cdot$ is the group operation, and $e$ is the identity element, and then the triple of $\Pi$-types represents the three laws that the group operation must obey. (We only have three since the type of the group operation, $\cdot : G \to G \to G$ gives us closure for free.)

Comment: Possibly stupid question. In a naive understanding of "predicativeness", the neutral element axiom of a group is impredicative, since it posits the existence of an element e for which ae = ea = a for all a, and e itself is in the scope of the universal quantifier. In the type theory formulation, it looks like the exact same statement is made, and somehow it is no longer impredicative? What is the difference exactly?

Comment: I don't know if I have the right background to answer your question confidently, but I think this comes from the fact that here $e$ isn't defined in terms of the laws—it's given and then proven to obey those laws.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Then the definition is not so much the definition of a group, it is the definition of a group $G$ with neutral element $e.$ I assume the important introductory remark can be stated and proved in type theory that if $G$ is a group with neutral element $e$ and neutral element $e',$ then $e = e'$?

Comment: Yes, here's a proof of that implemented using Idris https://gist.github.com/porglezomp/01b5eedf3172b70cb514559152099a52

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, type theory and group theory are much different.

Type theory is a theory about foundations of mathematics, like logic and set theory. It aims to generalize the concept of set, so that, for example, we can talk about something like the 'set' of all sets, which is actually not a set.

Group theory is a branch of algebra. It does not care about any foundations of mathematics, just taking them for granted. A group is a set with a binary operation satisfying some axioms, which is a set indeed.